# Where Xcode 8 places build logs?

Tags: xcode, logging, build, swift3

So, the question describes itself.

I want to edit the log after each build to cut out `swift 3` ugly warnings like `Result of call to '...' is unused`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode > Preferences > Locations you can define (or automatically accept the default path ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/) the location of the 'DerivedData' folder which is where the build logs are stored.

Go there and tap the -> arrow to see the folder organization. Apple introduces unique folder name extensions which would have to be determined and built into any script that would analyze or process the log.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go to your target settings and set the "Inhibit All Warnings" checkbox to ON.

[image: InhibitAllWarnings]

As for editing the transcript directly, I suspect this is something you **can't** easily do, as build transcripts can be exported (hold down the control key while clicking on a build log in the Report Navigator in the left side of the Xcode project window) and I think they must be stored in some Apple System Log-like binary format.

Comment: "Inhibit all warnings' isn't what I need. I'll be looking forward to find a way to externally read build logs...